# Как получить следующий элемент после выбранного?

Tags: html, css

Есть список:

Как получить доступ к :after сразу после ul, если список имеет класс `.tree-visible`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так - но не сработало:

```
.tree-visible:after {
  content: "-";
}

 .tree-visible ~ :after {
   content: "-";
 }
```

Полный код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::after` в этом примере принадлежит родительскому `li`, а селекторами нельзя добираться до родительских элементов.

---

Есть селектор [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), который не поддерживается ни в одном браузере... (¬_¬")

```
li:has(>ul.tree-visible)::after {
  content: "Mooo...";
}
```

Берет все `li`, непосредственно внутри которых есть `ul.tree-visible`.

---

К псевдоэлементу косвенно можно добраться через JS (если по каким-то причинам нельзя заранее отметить нужные `li` отдельным классом):

```js
(function() {
  var ul = document.querySelectorAll(".tree-visible");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < ul.length; i++) {
    ul[i].parentNode.classList.add("tree-visible-parent");
  }
})();
```

```css
.tree-visible-parent::after { /* <-- */
  content: "Bubu!";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <ul class="tree-visible">Test</ul>
</li>

<li>
  <ul class="not">Test</ul>
</li>
```